# Is it possible to get the value of an integer that was in the constructor of a class in that same class?

Tags: java

I've just started working with Java and I've run into a small problem. The program is in dutch but it's basically a simple Battleship type of thing. The class Boot creates a boat, with row, column, direction and size as constructors. The first method shows all coordinates of the boat, the second method tells you if the coordinates you entered correspond to the coordinates of the boat and the last method SHOULD take another Boot object (which will be called tweedeboot) and check to see if they overlap. I think the problem is that the x and y values used in the last method aren't the ones of tweedeboat but the values declared at the beginning of my class. 
How do I work around this? 
Thanks in advance!

```
public class Boot
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public boolean horizontaal;
    public int vakjes;

    public Boot(int rij, int kolom, boolean horizontaal, int aantalVakjes)
    {
        y = rij;
        x = kolom;
        this.horizontaal = horizontaal;
        vakjes = aantalVakjes;

    }  

    public void toonBoot()
    {
       ...
    }

    public boolean isRaak(int rij, int kolom)
    {
        ...
    }

    public boolean overlaptBoot(Boot tweedeboot)
    {
       boolean overlapping = false;

           int rij = y;
           int kolom = x;
           ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the ones from `tweedeboot`, you need to do `tweedeboot.x` and `tweedeboot.y`, so from within your `toonBoot` method you could compare

`x` to `tweedeboot.x`

`y` to `tweedeboot.y`